# What do "random sample" and "particular population" mean in clustering?

Tags: population, clustered-standard-errors, cluster-sample

Yesterday, from a suggestion of @Dimitriy V. Masterov [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531782/when-we-can-ignore-clustering), I saw from the [given link](https://blogs.worldbank.org/impactevaluations/when-should-you-cluster-standard-errors-new-wisdom-econometrics-oracle) about one of the reason we can avoid clustering is

> You want to say something about the association between schooling and
> wages in a **particular population**, and are using a **random sample** of
> workers from this population. Then there is no need to adjust the
> standard errors for clustering at all, even if clustering would change
> the standard errors.

I am not fully understanding the words "**particular population**" and "**random sample**" here. For example, in one paper, [Dasgupta, 2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300) examines the impact of anticollusion laws on firms' asset growth in a global context *where firms are not utility and financial firms*. So, whether in their case, this research satisfies two conditions "**random sample**" and "**particular population**"?